# sonar-runner excluding files

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am working on a project and have successfully run the build script on  the source code.

I am able to run sourcemeter successfully and able to run sonar-runner successfully. But the output in the SonarQube dashboard does not show all the files indexed during sonar-runner run. It looks like over 26,000 files have been excluded.

During the execution of sonar-runner, I see that

```
13:15:42.366 INFO  - 26842 files indexed
```

but when it completes, I get:

```
13:55:01.504 INFO -  67 files indexed
```

How can I configure Sonar, so that it indexes all files?

Comment: How many files show up in your project in SonarQube?

Comment: 67 files, 14 directories

Comment: Do the extensions of the ignored files match extensions configured for languages in your instance? You can check a language's file extension configuration at *Administration > \[Language] > File suffixes*

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find the path to the language file extension in SQ dashboard. However, I installed the community edition of c++ plugin on SQ dashbaord and change the sonar.language=c++ in sonar-project.properties file and ran sonar again. This time i got a better output in the SQ dashboard. Files = 6,763. Directories=465 and Lines of Code=738,828. But the MetricHunter is not available anymore.

Comment: Seems like i have to use sonar.language=cpp for my project. I have gone back to the original settings for my sonar-project.properties file. sonar-runner runs successfully but during the analysis, i see that 6k+ files are indexed but also 6k files are excluded so I onloy have 74 files showing in SQ dashboard. I have removed sona.exclusions from sonar properties file but still the same result.

Comment: I noticed that it's after running - Running SourceMeter toolchain... 1000s of files are excluded from my result to SQ. Any advise will be appreciated.